# activity dashlet not showing results

Tags: activities, ajax, dashboard

On the dashboard, the activity dashlet is not showing any results for me.
I havent heard anyone on this system ever seeing results there.

There is no ajax error, but the snippet it calls is

```
civicrm/ajax/contactactivity?snippet=4&context=dashlet&cid=3
```

(3 is me) .. if I call that directly, it returns an error

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>
> is not of the type Integer
>
> Return to home page.

anyone know whats wrong ? do I actually have to assign activity types to myself and if so, where ?

---

Powered by CiviCRM 4.5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, go try creating an activity on someone's record and assigning it to yourself.  If it doesn't show up in the dashlet, you have a problem, because that's what the dashlet is for.

Comment: Got it, that works. I was expecting something else, really. I was expecting the widget to show all database activity (that I have the right to see).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are wanting is to create a dashlet from the activity *report*.

- Go to **Reports > Contact Reports > Activity**
- Set up your report with the columns you wish
- Check the "Available for Dashboard?" option.
- Save the report.
- Go back to the CiviCRM dashboard, click the configure button, and add your report.